# while Loop for vowel counter

Tags: javascript, java, counter

I am trying to get a while loop program where it counts the number of vowels and takes the vowels out of the sentences, also repeating the process until the user inputs quit. I am having trouble getting the while loop to work.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class blank1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a Sentence: (Enter quit to exit) ");
        String input1 = input.nextLine();
        int vowelCount = 0;

        while(input.equals("quit")){

            System.out.println("Enter a Sentence: (Enter quit to exit) ");
            for (char c : input1.toCharArray())
            {
                switch(c)
                {

                    case 'A':
                    case 'a':

                    case 'E':
                    case 'e':

                    case 'I':
                    case 'i':

                    case 'O':
                    case 'o':

                    case 'U':
                    case 'u':
                        vowelCount++;

                        System.out.println(vowelCount);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does *"having trouble"* mean? What is happening now, and what do you expect to be happening?

Comment: Try adding a not operator: `while (! input.equals("quit")) {`

Comment: Also, move the `println(vowelCount)` *after* the loop, move the second `println("Enter ...")` after that, and add a `input1 = input.nextLine();` after that, and do `vowelCount = 0` right inside the loop.

Comment: when i try while( ! input.equals("quit")){ it continues to run without stop and just counts numbers

Comment: @AndreDorsey Because you don't have an `input.nextLine()` inside the loop. See bullet 4 in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

- Add a not operator: `while (! input.equals("quit")) {`
- Move the `println(vowelCount)` after the loop
- Move the second `println("Enter ...")` after that
- Add a `input1 = input.nextLine()` after that
- Do `vowelCount = 0` right inside the loop

To not do the print + nextLine in two places, try this instead:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence: (Enter quit to exit) ");
    String text = input.nextLine();
    if (text.equals("quit"))
        break;
    int vowelCount = 0;
    for (char c : text.toCharArray())
        switch (c) {
            case 'A': case 'a':
            case 'E': case 'e':
            case 'I': case 'i':
            case 'O': case 'o':
            case 'U': case 'u':
                vowelCount++;
        }
    System.out.println("Found " + vowelCount + " vowels");
}
```

Comment: one more question, how would i go about taking the vowels out of the sentence and printing that out with the output of how many vowels the program has counted

Comment: Create a list. Add them to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are looping while input equals "quit". Instead, you want to loop while input **does not** equal "quit".

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature of the while loop

from

`while(input.equals("quit"))`

to

`while( ! input.equals("quit"))`

Comment: now it counts but when i input quit it keeps running

Comment: Use break statement at the  end of each case. eg 
`case 'A':{
       statements;
       break;
}`